# gnuplot does not draw legend lines in epslatex terminal

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot

I have this "MWE":

```
set grid
set key right top
set title '$\sqrt{N}^{g(H)}$' offset 0,1.5

f(x) = 100 ** (2 - x - log(1 - 0.5 * (cos(pi * x) ** 2)) / log(100))
g(x) = 100 ** (2 - x)

G = '$g(H) = \, g_{simple}(H)$'
F = '$g(H) = g_{verbose}(H)$'

set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#a82828' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 3

set style line 2 \
    linecolor rgb '#516db0' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 3

set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:22000]
set xtics 0, 0.2 format "%.1f"
set terminal epslatex size 10.0cm,10.0cm color colortext 
set output 'RunningTimeCurvesFull.tex'

set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#a82828' linetype 1 linewidth 3
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#516db0' linetype 1 linewidth 3

# set xlabel 'Entropy' # Ignore
# set ylabel 'Theoretical work' # Ignore

plot g(x) title G with lines ls 1, f(x) title F with lines ls 2
exit
```

The above snippet produces a `RunningTimeCurvesFull.tex` file. When I `\input{RunningTimeCurvesFull}`, I get:

[image: Unfunky plot]

Note above that there is no red and blue lines to the right of the legend. How could I fix it?

**Edit**

I use gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 4 and MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.10 (MiKTeX 22.7)

**Edit 2**

After trying the solution by @theozh,  I get the following output:

[image: Unfunky plot]

Seems better, but has double y-axis label and the legend lines (red and blue) are still not there.

Comment: what is your Edit2 image? gnuplot output or LaTeX output? If LaTeX output, how does the gnuplot output look like and which format is it, PDF?

Comment: @theozh Oops, forgot to mention that. It's an `\input{RunningTimeCurvesFull}` in the LaTeX document.  The file `RunningTimeCurvesFull.tex` is generated by gnuplot cairolatex termnial.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script (gnuplot 5.4.1, Win10) which created a `.tex` file an `.eps` file. If I look a the `.eps` file (IrfanView & GhostScript), it *has* a red and blue line:

[image]

However, I didn't manage to include this `.eps` into a LaTeX PDF document. I am using MiKTeX, TeXStudio, pdfLaTeX under Win10. Apparently, since pdfLaTeX cannot handle `.eps` directly, it should convert it into `.pdf` via `miktex-epstopdf`. However, for some reason it was not creating or finding the `.pdf`. Searching on tex.stackexchange did not solve the issue.

So, I am not sure if the following would be a solution for you, but it worked for me: Instead, I was using `cairolatex` terminal, which creates a `.tex` and `.pdf`:

```
set terminal cairolatex size 10.0cm,10.0cm color
set output 'RunningTimeCurvesFull.tex'

... <your script> ...

set output
```

Now, I can use these generated files in a LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{RunningTimeCurvesFull}
\end{document}
```

and get the following output (screenshot from PDF):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time, yet, alas, that does not solve my issue on my box.

Comment: @coderodde So, have you tried with cairolatex and it doesn't draw the legend lines? Do you really need an .eps file? To me .eps seems to be a leftover from ancient times which is replaced by .pdf. Maybe I am wrong, but then I would be interested in learning about a reason to keep going with .eps.

Comment: Does the *.eps file produced by gnuplot on your machine contain those lines or not?   If it does (which is what we are seeing on our machines) then your problem must be coming at the LaTeX stage, not the gnuplot stage.  You might have better luck asking for help on a different forum.

Comment: @Ethan yes, the .eps are _with_ the two lines as curve _and_ in the legend as shown in the first picture. I know that the missing step is the conversion from .eps to .pdf with MiKTeX and it is my special LaTeX issue, which, however, I couldn't solve (so far) by searching tex.stackexchange. I don't see (yet) the advantage to use .eps.

Comment: @theozh - yeah, you showed that you get the key lines in the *.eps file.  The question was whether this is also true for coderodde.   I'm trying to determine whether this is a gnuplot problem or a MiKTeX problem.   As to why eps...   Some people want to use plain latex, and for that eps is a standard format.  If you intend to use pdflatex then yes, it would be better to use pdf from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Your script worked for me here using the epslatex terminal in gnuplot 5.4.1 and latex from texlive-2020.

A minimal TeX document wrapping this is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} %epslatex needs this
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\input{RunningTimeCurvesFull}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, yet, alas, that does not solve my issue.