# gnuplot - an epslatex terminal does not plot the x-label

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot

I have this small MWE

```
set title font "Monospaced,13"
set grid

f(x) = 5 * log(x) / log(2) 
g(x) = 5 + sqrt(5 + x)

F = '$5 \log_2(x)$'
G = '$5 + \sqrt{5 + x}$'

# set yrange [0:300]
set xrange [0:4000]
set xlabel 'My Label'

set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#a82828' linetype 1 linewidth 5 pointtype 5 pointsize 1.5
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#516db0' linetype 1 linewidth 5 pointtype 9 pointsize 1.5

plot f(x) title F with lines ls 1, g(x) title G with lines ls 2 

set terminal epslatex background rgb "grey" standalone size 10.0cm,10.0cm color colortext
set output 'RunTimeComparisonTreeIndexed.tex'

set style rect fc rgb "white" fs
set object 1 rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind
set key left top box lt -1 lw 2 opaque

replot
exit
```

The above script relies on [this TeX-post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/662229/gnuplot-cannot-typeset-latex-title-for-a-plot).

It gives me:

[image: fdfd]

(Note that the x-label "My Label" is missing.)

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I use the following LaTeX snippet for including the plot PDF file (see the linked TeX.StackExchange post):

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
%\setlength{\voffset}{0cm}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{0cm}
\includepdf[pages={1},pagecommand={},width=0.5\textwidth]{RunTimeComparisonTreeIndexed.pdf}
%\setlength{\voffset}{- 10cm}
%\setlength{\hoffset}{-10cm}
\label{fig:rtcti}
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Since the x-label is text, it is not included in the .eps file, but in the .tex file. All the tics labels are missing in your image as well. So, this might be an issue with your TeX setup. What is your (La)TeX code? How do you include your .tex file (which embeds the .eps) into your final document?

Comment: @theozh Thank you for your time. I have added a TeX snippet including the plot PDF.

Comment: @theozh Basically, I convert the plot file to a thefile.tex file; then, I `pdflatex thefile.tex` and use, finally, the LaTeX snippet in the Edit - section to include the resuling .pdf file.

Comment: Why do you create an .eps if you convert it to .pdf and embed it as .pdf later? Why not using terminal cairolatex and creating a .pdf directly? Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73513581/7295599

Comment: @theozh Fair enough. I will give cairolatex another try.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not "fluent" in LaTeX, so this was also a good exercise for me and will be a memory aid for myself.
Use the terminal `cairolatex` and directly create a PDF with TeX text formatting without detour via `.eps`. I used MiKTeX and pdflatex under Win10. gnuplot will create two files (`SO74149797.tex` and `SO74149797.pdf`).

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.4.2 for fillcolor for keybox)

```
### create pdf with TeX text formatting via cairolatex
reset session

f(x) = 5 * log(x) / log(2) 
g(x) = 5 + sqrt(5 + x)

F = '$5 \log_2(x)$'
G = '$5 + \sqrt{5 + x}$'

set title font "Monospaced,13"
set xrange [0:4000]
set xlabel 'My Label'
set grid
set key left top box lt -1 lw 2 opaque fc "grey"    # fillcolor option fc for gnuplot>=5.4.2
set key width 1 spacing 1.5

set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#a82828' linetype 1 linewidth 5 pointtype 5 pointsize 1.5
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#516db0' linetype 1 linewidth 5 pointtype 9 pointsize 1.5

set terminal cairolatex pdf input size 10.0cm,10.0cm color colortext
set output 'SO74149797.tex'

plot f(x) title F with lines ls 1, \
     g(x) title G with lines ls 2 

set output
### end of script
```

**LaTeX:** (important to add these packages)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[cp1252]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

    \input{SO74149797}

\end{document}
```

**Result:** (screenshot from final PDF document)

[image]