# Making latex figures with a single file as output in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have been using the `epslatex` terminal to make scienctific figures, for a paper, in gnuplot and I get the output in the form of two files - .tex file and .eps file - with the .tex containing all the labels and titles and .eps file containing the unlabelled figure.  However, when I submitted the paper, the journal said that having the two files for a figure is problematic for them and that I should upload the figures as  single files.

I am unable to find a way to do that without abandoning gnuplot all together, and in that case it would be a massive task replotted all the figures using a different programming language.

Is there any way to get the figure as a single output file and get rid of the .tex file?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this maybe solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152060/7295599

Comment: @theozh That post actually does not explain how to do it in a single .pdf or .eps file.

Comment: well, gnuplot will create a .pdf document and a .tex document. In this post there is another LaTeX document. Compile this document with pdfLaTeX and you will get a single PDF document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest having a look at the gnuplot [latex terminal guide](https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs/latex_demo.pdf).  You have several options, depending on whether the journal would prefer the figure as purely PDF or purely TeX.  In my experience it's usually PDF these days, but it depends on the journal.

Either way you go, I recommend using the tikz terminal.  It outputs a single *.tex file which the journal might accepts as-is, or you can run the TeX file through pdflatex to produce a single PDF file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to use the tikz terminal. I am doing exactly as stated in the link to produce the pdf file. My last command is ``!pdflatex figure``` but the terminal says ```sh:1 : pdflatex: not found``` .

Comment: I installed pdflatex in ubuntu and now its working. So, you can ignore my previous comment.