# How to place a text below plots using multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using Gnuplot version 5.4. I have 4 plots generated by the code:

```
set size 1, 1
set origin 0.0, 0.0
set term postscript eps enhanced color 'Helvetica' 15
set output 'sig_tau2.eps'
set multiplot layout 2,2
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set size square
set xtics ("0" 0, "175" 175, "350" 350) font "Helvetica,15"
set ytics ("0" 0, "2" 2, "4" 4) font "Helvetica,15"
set cbtics ("-0.0075" -0.0075, "0" 0, "0.0075" 0.0075) font "Helvetica,15"
set xlabel "{/Symbol t}" font "Helvetica,15"
set label "{/Symbol s}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph -0.3, graph 0.6
set label "{Re{/Symbol z}_{max}}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph 1.3, graph 0.5
set pm3d map #Achte auf das Format der Datendatei (Leerzeilen!)
set cbrange [-0.0075:0.0075]
set xrange [0:350]
set yrange [0:4]
set palette defined (-0.0075 0 0 1, 0 0 1 0, 0 "yellow", 0.0075 1 0 0)
set colorbox
set title "(a)" font "Helvetica Bold,15"
unset key
splot "1.dat" u 1:2:4 title""

unset xtics
unset ytics
unset cbtics
unset xlabel
unset label
unset label
unset cbrange
unset xrange
unset yrange
unset pm3d

set xtics ("0" 0, "175" 175, "350" 350) font "Helvetica,15"
set ytics ("0" 0, "2" 2, "4" 4) font "Helvetica,15"
set cbtics ("-0.0075" -0.0075, "0" 0, "0.0075" 0.0075) font "Helvetica,15"
set xlabel "{/Symbol t}" font "Helvetica,15"
set label "{/Symbol s}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph -0.3, graph 0.6
set label "{Re{/Symbol z}_{max}}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph 1.3, graph 0.5
set pm3d map #Achte auf das Format der Datendatei (Leerzeilen!)
set cbrange [-0.0075:0.0075]
set xrange [0:350]
set yrange [0:4]
set palette defined (-0.0075 0 0 1, 0 0 1 0, 0 "yellow", 0.0075 1 0 0)
set colorbox
set title "(b)"
unset key
splot "2.dat" u 1:2:4 title""

unset xtics
unset ytics
unset cbtics
unset xlabel
unset label
unset label
unset cbrange
unset xrange
unset yrange
unset pm3d

set xtics ("0" 0, "175" 175, "350" 350) font "Helvetica,15"
set ytics ("0" 0, "4" 4, "8" 8) font "Helvetica,15"
set cbtics ("-0.0075" -0.0075, "0" 0, "0.0075" 0.0075) font "Helvetica,15"
set xlabel "{/Symbol t}" font “Helvetica,15"
set label "{/Symbol s}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph -0.3, graph 0.6
set label "{Re{/Symbol z}_{max}}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph 1.3, graph 0.5
set pm3d map #Achte auf das Format der Datendatei (Leerzeilen!)
set cbrange [-0.0075:0.0075]
set xrange [0:350]
set yrange [0:8]
set palette defined (-0.0075 0 0 1, 0 0 1 0, 0 "yellow", 0.0075 1 0 0)
set colorbox
set title "(c)"
unset key
splot "3.dat" u 1:2:4 title""

unset xtics
unset ytics
unset cbtics
unset xlabel
unset label
unset label
unset cbrange
unset xrange
unset yrange
unset pm3d

set xtics ("0" 0, "175" 175, "350" 350) font "Helvetica,15" 
set ytics ("0" 0, "6" 6, "12" 12) font "Helvetica,15"
set cbtics ("-0.0075" -0.0075, "0" 0, "0.0075" 0.0075) font "Helvetica,15"
set xlabel "{/Symbol t}" font "Helvetica,15"
set label "{Figure 2: Stability region of the endemic equilibrium in σ-τ plane. Color code denotes the maximum real part of ζ.}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph -0.3, graph -0.1
set label "{/Symbol s}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph -0.3, graph 0.6
set label "{Re{/Symbol z}_{max}}" font "Helvetica,15" at graph 1.3, graph 0.5
set pm3d map #Achte auf das Format der Datendatei (Leerzeilen!)
set cbrange [-0.0075:0.0075]
set xrange [0:350]
set yrange [0:12]
set palette defined (-0.0075 0 0 1, 0 0 1 0, 0 "yellow", 0.0075 1 0 0)
set colorbox
set title "(d)"
unset key
splot "4.dat" u 1:2:4 title""
unset multiplot
```

and I would like to place a text below these graphs like the one in this picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vP5w.jpg)

Would it be possible to do this while maintaining the plots sizes?

I tried to use set label at positions but the text does appear in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to add some bottom margin to a multiplot in order to have space for a label (in your case figure caption).
To my opinion, the figure caption should be the task of the text editor (LaTeX, Word, Writer, etc.).

Anyway, check `help multiplot`. You have the options `margins` and `spacing`.

- If you need full flexibility then you have to place and size each subplot via `set origin` and `set size` (check `help origin` and `help size`)
- set the figure `label 1` only before the last plot and in screen coordinates, since `label 1` would be placed again in each plot unless you `unset label 1` or all via `unset label`.
- By the way you don't have to unset all setting and set them again, just overwrite them. But maybe there is a reason why you do so.

Check the following minimized example below which requires some tuning for your specific case.

**Script:**

```
### create some bottom margin for text in multiplot environment
reset session

set multiplot layout 2,2 margins 0.1,0.90,0.2,0.95 spacing 0.2

    set view map
    set size square

    set title "(a)"
    set xlabel "h"
    set ylabel "γ" rotate by 0
    splot x*y w pm3d
    
    set title "(b)"
    set xlabel "ʎ"
    set ylabel "ω"
    splot x*y**2 w pm3d
    
    set title "(c)"
    set ylabel "h"
    splot x**2*y w pm3d
    
    set label 1 at screen 0.05, screen 0.04 "{/:Bold Fig.1} This is some figure text..."
    set title "(d)"
    set ylabel "γ"
    splot x**2*y**2 w pm3d

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you theozh for your help! Do you have any idea of how to have the caption written in a laTex way?

Comment: @Althaqel If you want to use LaTeX text then you have to use a LaTeX type terminal, e.g. `cairolatex`. Maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152060/7295599 However, usually, LaTeX will create the figure caption and the number in a document. The figure number and caption are usually not included in the graph itself.

Comment: you mean after obtaining the tex and pdf files, we use them on MacTex?

Comment: @Althaqel I don't know MacTex. But I would assume that you include the graph via some `\begin{figure} \input{yourFile} \caption{Your caption}  \end{figure}`. And final numbering will be handled by LaTeX.

Comment: I am sorry I am a bit confused. In your response here stackoverflow.com/a/74152060/7295599, where did you use the latex code?

Comment: @Althaqel you need a LaTeX environment installed. In the command line something like `pdflatex yourTeXFile.tex`, but not the gnuplot generated one... the other one.

Comment: Thank you @theozh for your support. I think I am going to write everything using Overleaf where it takes care of figure captions for me.

Comment: @Althaqel yes, you definitely should use your LaTeX distribution to organize figure numbers and figure captions. You don't want to manually recreate the graph every time your caption or figure number changes.